# How to link pages with Framework7?

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, google-chrome, html-framework-7

I'm experimenting with Framework7 with this fun chat app I'm trying to make using PhoneGap previews. The thing is, I've never used Framework7 before and I'm having a tough time linking pages together under my main page.

I have a string of text with a `<a href="">` tag, that I want to link to a form for people to sign up and create their profiles on the app. I've created a separate html file that I tried linking with the `<a href="signup.html">`, because that's what the examples showed that you can do, but when I test it, it doesn't work, the chrome inspector gives me this feedback:

`framework7.min.js:23 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:...Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.`

Below is my code, and the last string on the bottom is what I'm trying to link to the singup page with the form, any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<!-- Status bar overlay for full screen mode (PhoneGap) -->
    <div class="statusbar-overlay"></div>
    <!-- Views -->
    <div class="views">
        <!-- Your main view, should have "view-main" class -->
        <div class="view view-main">
            <!-- Pages container, because we use fixed-through navbar and toolbar, it has additional appropriate classes-->
            <div class="pages navbar-through toolbar-through">
                <!-- Page, "data-page" contains page name -->
                <div data-page="index" class="page">
                    <!-- Scrollable page content -->
                    <div class="page-content login-screen-content">
                        <div class="login-screen-title"><img src="img/logo.png" width="130px" height="130px"></div>
                        <div class="login-screen-title">Welcome to<br>J Chat</div>
                        <p class="tour-content" style="text-align: center">Login below to get started!</p>
                        <form>
                        <div class="list-block">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="item-content">
                                    <div class="item-inner">
                                        <div class="item-title label">Email</div>
                                        <div class="input-inner">
                                            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="item-content">
                                    <div class="item-inner">
                                        <div class="item-title label">Password</div>
                                        <div class="input-inner">
                                            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                        <div class="list-block">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="home.html" class="button button-intro login ripple">Login</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Link to another page -->
                        <div class="list-block" style="margin-top: 1em;">
                            <p class="tour-content">
                                Don't have an account yet?<br>
                                <a href="signup.html">Click here</a> to sign up!
                            </p>
                        </div>

                    </form>


                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Possibly duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local

Answer (score 0):

Is your file on your local server? If you compressed the folder and build it with phone gap, on your device links will work. However if you are previewing on a desktop you have to place the dist folder on your local server. 
I use Apache, so I've placed the dist folder in the htdocs folder and then navigate towards it, from my browser and that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

put your files in some www server - it's impossible to serve the html files from local directory.